# How do I lock an account after too much false logins by using container managed auhentication in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, java-ee-6

A Java EE RESTful service is deployed on JBoss AS7 and uses container managed authentication. Now I want to lock an account after three false login attempts. Is there a way to do this via the container authentication, and how can I do this?

If not, is there a way to get the information wheter or not a login was successful (including the login name)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JBoss form based authentication with account lockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845107/jboss-form-based-authentication-with-account-lockout)

Answer (score 1):

How to do this depends on the realm you use for authentication.

If you use LDAP authentication you usually can configure this on the LDAP directory level.

If you use some kind of database realm you most likely will have to extend the LoginModule your are using an plug your own version into the JBoss' security domain. Needless to say that you need a realm where you are able to keep track of login attempts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using a database realm. Can you please provide an example or add a reference to a documentation for such a security feature?